# Laravel - Column name with _ returning a t_lnumber error

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, database-schema

My database schema has the following column names:

```
1_1, 1_2, 1_3 etc...
```

Within my Controller, I am trying to add to these columns, but it's returning the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier
(T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
```

The line at which it's occurring is:

```
  $audit->1_1 = Input::get('1_1');
```

The full snippet of the code is below:

```
public function postAddFullAudit()
  {
    $audit = new Audit();
    $audit->site_id = Input::get('site_id');
    $audit->1_1 = Input::get('1_1');
    $audit->1_2 = Input::get('1_2');
    $audit->1_3 = Input::get('1_3');
    $audit->1_4 = Input::get('1_4');
    $audit->1_5 = Input::get('1_5');
    $audit->save();
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Try this: $audit->{'1_1'}

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you @Subzeta.